sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint @result parsing error
I have azure sql with azure api manager calling various microsoft services such as graph - outlook, azure maps and external rest api's from sql using the sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint stored proc.
For 1 of the calls, the sp_invoke stored proc fails with a @result cannot parse json error which is part of the response passed from APIM back to SQL. The request runs as expected and the external endpoint (which is a post call) returns the expected result on the 3rd party api.
MS APIM support have advised to turn on the trace in the header in the sp_invoke stored proc in order to identify what is causing the issue. Since the trace location is returned in the response, and the response is not being returned in SQL and simply fails, I cant get the trace location in SQL and i cant see what the trace location in APIM.
I have tested the 3rd party api call in Postman and then in APIM and the calls run as expected without error.
When i run the call in the azure sql main proc, the sp_invoke stored proc runs and then intermittantly returns an error on the @result cannot be parsed (for the same 3rd party post call sometimes there is an error and sometimes no error). The @result is part of the sp_invoke response and is formed in APIM.
Note when testing in Postman and APIM, the calls are running as expected so the response is correctly formed.
Please advise how to resolve the above - can i add an APIM polivy to apply a fix to the result element of the response from APIM to SQL?

The issue you're encountering seems to be related to inconsistent behavior in the response that is being returned from APIM to Azure SQL via the sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint stored procedure. The error you mentioned about the @result not being able to parse JSON could be due to a variety of reasons, such as malformed responses, unexpected formatting, or intermittent response structure issues from the third-party API.


sp_invoid_external_rest_endpoint @result Parse error.

The error indicates that there may be a problem with the way JSON is parsed in SQL. Check below. There are many reasons for this problem.

Validating JSON Responses: Ensure that JSON responses from third-party APIs are properly formatted, parentheses, commas. Or missing quotes can cause a parsing error.
Check SQL Version: Make sure your Azure SQL database version supports the specific JSON format you are using.
APIM Policy Modification: You can add a modification policy to APIM to modify the JSON response before passing it to SQL.

